# How to get middle character from a string using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this.

```
----------------
|Id  | Name    |
----------------
|1   |Apple    |
|2   |banana   |
|3   |Orange   |
|4   |Grapes   |
|5   |Mango    |
----------------
```

I need middle character from each string.My result is to be like this

```
--------------------
|Id  | Name    |MidChar|
------------------------
|1   |Apple    | p |
|2   |banana   | n(or)a|
|3   |Orange   | a(or)n|
|4   |Grape   | a |
|5   |Mango   | n |
-------------------
```

Please give some solutions or ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEN` and `Substring` function

Try this

```
declare @Name varchar(10) = 'Apple'

select substring(@Name,LEN(@Name)/2+1,1)
```

Comment: But problem occured in mango.i got 'a'  as per your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try the below query. It should suit all your specified requirements.

```
SELECT [Id],[Name],CASE WHEN LEN(Name)%2 != 0
       THEN SUBSTRING(Name,LEN(Name)/2+1,1)
       ELSE SUBSTRING(Name,LEN(Name)/2,1)+' (or) '+ SUBSTRING(Name,LEN(Name)/2 + 1,1)
   END AS [MidChar] 
FROM [yourTable]
```

Kindly share your feedback.

Comment: @Prasanna Kumar J - Did the query help?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script,

```
SELECT  Id,Name,SUBSTRING(Name,CEILING(LEN(Name)/2.0),1) AS MidChar
FROM    MyTable
```